# Simplify code. Mine works but looks ugly like hell

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have trouble dealing with Python. I have PD dataframe and i need to drop all rows,  which are coming after specific values (in code values are written to list called years) All values should be grouped by company name, because these obserevations belong to the companies mentioned in column 'inn_main'. I really dont get it how to do this with Pandas functionality. I have found a way though, but it is very ugly and not much efficient.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'inn_main':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Tesla', 'Tesla', 'Tesla'], 'Help':['OK', 'OK', 2013, 'OK','OK', 2014, 'OK']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
droper=[]
block=0
years=[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]
for j in range(len(list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main'])))):
    alarm=0
    for i in range(len(list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main']))[j][1].index.values)):
        if list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main']))[j][1][list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main']))[j][1].index.values[i].astype(int)] in years:
            block=1
            alarm=1
        if block==1:
            block=0
        else:
            if alarm==1:
                droper.append(list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main']))[j][1].index.values[i].astype(int))   
df.drop(index=droper)
```

Could you please tell me what am i exactly doing wrong? Are there any shortcuts?

Comment: Post an example of what you want the DataFrame output to look like

Comment: And can you try explaining in words the logic you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly short:

```
df.groupby('inn_main').apply(lambda grp:
    grp[~grp.Help.isin(years).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0).astype(bool)])
```

The result is:

```
           inn_main  Help
inn_main                 
Apple    0    Apple    OK
         1    Apple    OK
         2    Apple  2013
Tesla    4    Tesla    OK
         5    Tesla  2014
```

Details:

- `df.groupby('inn_main')` - group the DataFrame by companies.
- `apply(lambda grp:` - apply a lambda function to each group.
- `grp.Help.isin(years)` - is *Help* value in *years*?
- `.cumsum()` - cumulative sum for the above question.
- `shift(fill_value=0)` - shift the result by 1 row down, filling
  any *NaN* (actually the first item) with *0*.
- `astype(bool)` - convert integers to *bool*.
- `~` - negate the above result
- `[...]` - use the above result in *boolean indexing*.
- `grp[...]` - return "good" rows from the current group (they will
  be the part of the result for the current group).

**Caution**: The solution by *ASGM* drops **only the first** row
with *OK* after any row with *Help* contained in *years*.

To confirm it, add another row containing *Tesla* and *OK* to
your DataFrame and run his code.

The result is:

```
  inn_main  Help
0    Apple    OK
1    Apple    OK
2    Apple  2013
4    Tesla    OK
5    Tesla  2014
7    Tesla    OK
```

so row with index == *7* (which should be deleted), is present.

Comment: I couldn't tell whether this is what OP wanted or not - probably this is the right solution for many cases!

Comment: I don't agree. The OP wrote clearly: *drop **all** rows, which are coming after specific values* (not the first only).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really meant to drop all rows after specific values.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you're asking for, but here's what I think you want.  Given the following dataframe...

```
   Help inn_main
0    OK    Apple
1    OK    Apple
2  2013    Apple
3    OK    Apple
4    OK    Tesla
5  2014    Tesla
6    OK    Tesla
```

...you want to identify each row where `df.Help` is in a list of `years`, and drop the row that comes after it (within the rows belonging to a given company).  If that's correct, you can do it much more simply:

```
years = range(2012, 2019)
df[~df.groupby('inn_main')['Help'].apply(lambda g: g.isin(years).shift().fillna(False))]
```

This will give:

```
   Help inn_main
0    OK    Apple
1    OK    Apple
2  2013    Apple
4    OK    Tesla
5  2014    Tesla
```

If you want to drop *all* the rows within a company that follow a given row, the thorough [answer by Valdi_Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60441244/2074981) shows how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about panda nor what you are trying to do, but here is the code refactored to iterate list instead of using indexes:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'inn_main':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Tesla', 'Tesla', 'Tesla'], 'Help':['OK', 'OK', 2013, 'OK','OK', 2014, 'OK']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
droper=[]
years=[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]
for j in list(df['Help'].groupby(df['inn_main'])):
    alarm=False
    for i in j[1].index.values:
        if j[1][i.astype(int)] in years:
            alarm=True
        elif alarm:
            droper.append(i.astype(int))   
df.drop(index=droper)
```

Comment: Lol the guy above knows much about pandas, he made it with 1 string :D